# Java , put JsonObject into JsonArray, but JsonArray take the same value at the end of the for loop

Tags: java, arrays, json, loops, for-loop

I am a novice in Java, on this code  I am trying to put JsonObect in a JsonArray , but  the things is the JsonArray only takes the last value and it is duplicate in it.

You do not need to understand all the code just the interesting part

I have put  the part Of the code which is interesting  in the field //******here******// code   //******end here******// and I have also put the json file if you want to test

For my part ,I have tried to put my values in List of JsonObject then put it in the JsonArray,but I have the same result.

I have also tried to use a Hash map with indices but it still do not working

If you print the JsonObject variable "Alldate"  you can see that it has  different values but When I put them in the JsonArray Array "ArrayBuckets", you will see That the  JsonArray has the same value which is the last values.

I do not understand because my jsonObject and Array are in the same loop.

Thanks .

Here is the code :

```
package jsonbi.bi;

import java.io.FileReader;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Enumeration;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Hashtable;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

import org.codehaus.jackson.JsonFactory;
import org.codehaus.jackson.JsonNode;
import org.codehaus.jackson.map.ObjectMapper;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;
import org.json.simple.parser.JSONParser;

import com.google.gson.Gson;

public class JsonBi9 {

    JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();
    JSONObject json;
    Object obj;
    Map.Entry<String, JsonNode> field;
    HashMap newmap = new HashMap();
    JsonFactory factory = new JsonFactory();
    private ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

    Gson gson = new Gson();

    JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray();
    JSONObject Alldate = new JSONObject();

    JSONObject BucketsObject = new JSONObject();
    JSONObject Groupe = new JSONObject();
    JSONObject Aggregations = new JSONObject();
    JSONObject TheJson = new JSONObject();

    JSONArray ArrayBuckets = new JSONArray();

     Hashtable ht = new Hashtable();



     int j =0;

    public JsonBi9() {

        try {

            // here I am readind the json file
            obj = parser.parse(new FileReader("myjson2.json"));

            ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper(factory);

            JsonNode rootNode = mapper.readTree(obj.toString());

            Iterator<Map.Entry<String, JsonNode>> fieldsIterator = rootNode.getFields();

            JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(obj.toString());


            // here I am reading the fields in the json fields
            while (fieldsIterator.hasNext()) {

                field = fieldsIterator.next();

                newmap.put(field.getKey(), field.getValue());

                if (field.getKey().equals("aggregations")) {

                    System.out.println("hugo");

                    JSONObject aggregations = jsonObject.getJSONObject("aggregations");

                    JSONObject groupe = aggregations.getJSONObject("groupe");

                    JSONArray buckets = groupe.getJSONArray("buckets");



    for (int i11a = 0; i11a < buckets.length(); i11a++) {



    JSONObject obj1bucket = buckets.getJSONObject(i11a);


                        JSONObject date11 = obj1bucket.getJSONObject("date");

                        JSONArray obj11bucket = date11.getJSONArray("buckets");



                        List<String> listSubbucket = new ArrayList<String>();

                        for (int i11 = 0; i11 < obj11bucket.length(); i11++) {

                            listSubbucket.add(obj11bucket.getJSONObject(i11).toString());

                            // System.out.println(obj11bucket.getJSONObject(i11).toString());

                        }

                        jsonArray = new JSONArray();

                        for (int i11 = 0; i11 < listSubbucket.size(); i11++) {

                            JSONObject SubBucket = new JSONObject();

                            SubBucket.put("buckets", listSubbucket.get(i11));


                            getdocument(obj1bucket, Alldate);



//******************************here ********************************//

                            // System.out.println(SubBucket);
                            Alldate.put("date", SubBucket);


                            ArrayBuckets.put(Alldate);

                        //*µµ if you want to print the jsonObject and array

                        //  System.out.println(Alldate);
                            // System.out.println(ArrayBuckets);*

//*********************************end here ******************************//



                        } // end first  for loop

                    } //end second for loop

                    Enumeration e = ht.elements();

                    while(e.hasMoreElements())
                      System.out.println(e.nextElement());



                    getdocument(groupe, Groupe);

                    Groupe.put("buckets", ArrayBuckets);

                    Aggregations.put("groupe", Groupe);
                    // System.out.println(Aggregations);

                } // fin du if

                else {

                    // System.out.println("Key: " + field.getKey() + "\tValue:"
                    // + field.getValue());

                    TheJson.put(field.getKey(), field.getValue());

                } // fin du else

            } // fin du while

            // I put all the documents
            TheJson.put("aggregations", Aggregations);

            System.out.println(TheJson);


        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    public void getdocument(JSONObject obj1bucket, JSONObject Alldate) {

        // get the json documents in the subbuckets
        int i = 0;
        // JSONObject buckectinfos1 = new JSONObject();
        for (Iterator key = obj1bucket.keys(); key.hasNext();) {

            Object jsonkeys;
            try {
                jsonkeys = obj1bucket.get((String) key.next());

                Object jsonvalues = obj1bucket.names().getString(i);

                String jsonInString = gson.toJson(jsonkeys);

                if (!jsonkeys.getClass().getName().equals("org.json.JSONObject")
                        && !jsonkeys.getClass().getName().equals("org.json.JSONArray")) {


                } // fin du if
                i++;

            } catch (JSONException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        } // fin du for

    }

}
```

Here is the values in the JsonObject "alldate"  that I want to put  In the JsonArray "ArrayBuckets":

```
{"date":{"buckets":"{\"key_as_string\":\"2017-05-03T00:00:00.000Z\",\"doc_count\":1,\"value\":{\"value\":1},\"key\":1493769600000}"},"doc_count":"1","key":"\"a\""}
{"date":{"buckets":"{\"key_as_string\":\"2017-05-03T01:00:00.000Z\",\"doc_count\":2,\"value\":{\"value\":3},\"key\":1493776800000}"},"doc_count":"1","key":"\"a\""}
{"date":{"buckets":"{\"key_as_string\":\"2017-05-03T00:00:00.000Z\",\"doc_count\":4,\"value\":{\"value\":5},\"key\":1493769600000}"},"doc_count":"4","key":"\"b\""}
{"date":{"buckets":"{\"key_as_string\":\"2017-05-03T01:00:00.000Z\",\"doc_count\":5,\"value\":{\"value\":6},\"key\":1493773200000}"},"doc_count":"4","key":"\"b\""}
```

But I only have the last value duplicated in the JsonArray  "ArrayBuckets":

```
{"date":{"buckets":"{\"key_as_string\":\"2017-05-03T01:00:00.000Z\",\"doc_count\":5,\"value\":{\"value\":6},\"key\":1493773200000}"},"doc_count":"4","key":"\"b\""}
```

Here is the Json file :"myjson2.json"

```
{ 
  "took": 7, 
  "timed_out": false, 
  "_shards": { 
    "total": 5, 
    "successful": 5, 
    "failed": 0 
  }, 
  "hits": { 
    "total": 10, 
    "max_score": 0, 
    "hits": [] 
  }, 
  "aggregations": { 
    "groupe": { 
      "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0, 
      "sum_other_doc_count": 0, 
      "buckets": [ 
        { 
          "key": "a", 
          "doc_count": 1, 
          "date": { 
            "buckets": [ 
              { 
                "key_as_string": "2017-05-03T00:00:00.000Z", 
                "key": 1493769600000, 
                "doc_count": 1, 
                "value": { 
                  "value": 1 
                } 
              }, 
              { 
                "key_as_string": "2017-05-03T01:00:00.000Z", 
                "key": 1493776800000, 
                "doc_count": 2, 
                "value": { 
                  "value": 3 
                } 
              } 
            ] 
          } 
        }, 
        { 
          "key": "b", 
          "doc_count": 4, 
          "date": { 
            "buckets": [ 
              { 
                "key_as_string": "2017-05-03T00:00:00.000Z", 
                "key": 1493769600000, 
                "doc_count": 4, 
                "value": { 
                  "value": 5 
                } 
              }, 
              { 
                "key_as_string": "2017-05-03T01:00:00.000Z", 
                "key": 1493773200000, 
                "doc_count": 5, 
                "value": { 
                  "value": 6 
                } 
              } 

            ] 
          } 
        } 
      ] 
    } 
  } 
}
```

Here is the result of the code :

```
{  
   "_shards":"{\"total\":5,\"failed\":0,\"successful\":5}",
   "hits":"{\"hits\":[],\"total\":10,\"max_score\":0}",
   "took":"7",
   "timed_out":"false",
   "aggregations":{  
      "groupe":{  
         "doc_count_error_upper_bound":"0",
         "sum_other_doc_count":"0",
         "buckets":[  
            {  
               "date":{  
                  "buckets":"{\"key_as_string\":\"2017-05-03T01:00:00.000Z\",\"doc_count\":5,\"value\":{\"value\":6},\"key\":1493773200000}"
               },
               "doc_count":"4",
               "key":"\"b\""
            },
            {  
               "date":{  
                  "buckets":"{\"key_as_string\":\"2017-05-03T01:00:00.000Z\",\"doc_count\":5,\"value\":{\"value\":6},\"key\":1493773200000}"
               },
               "doc_count":"4",
               "key":"\"b\""
            },
            {  
               "date":{  
                  "buckets":"{\"key_as_string\":\"2017-05-03T01:00:00.000Z\",\"doc_count\":5,\"value\":{\"value\":6},\"key\":1493773200000}"
               },
               "doc_count":"4",
               "key":"\"b\""
            },
            {  
               "date":{  
                  "buckets":"{\"key_as_string\":\"2017-05-03T01:00:00.000Z\",\"doc_count\":5,\"value\":{\"value\":6},\"key\":1493773200000}"
               },
               "doc_count":"4",
               "key":"\"b\""
            }
         ]
      }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can only have one entry whith a name inside a JSONObject.

```
for (int i11 = 0; i11 < listSubbucket.size(); i11++) {

                        JSONObject SubBucket = new JSONObject();

                        SubBucket.put("buckets", listSubbucket.get(i11));


                        getdocument(obj1bucket, Alldate);

                        // System.out.println(SubBucket);
                        Alldate.put("date", SubBucket);


                        ArrayBuckets.put(Alldate);

                    //*µµ if you want to print the jsonObject and array

                    //  System.out.println(Alldate);
                        // System.out.println(ArrayBuckets);



                    } // end first  for loop
```

When you do this, in each loop you overwrite de value whith the key "date". If you want to have all your date in AllDate it have to be a JSONArray.

You can also replace `Alldate.put("date", SubBucket);` by `Alldate.put("date" + i, SubBucket);`

Answer (score 0):

Instead of declaring Alldate variable in the class scope, declare it in for loop. The error occurs because you have only one variable JsonObject to put to JsonArray. So the solution is to create each different JsonObject variable for each loop.

```html
for (int i11 = 0; i11 < listSubbucket.size(); i11++) {

                            JSONObject Alldate = new JSONObject();

                            ...

//******************************here ********************************//

                            // System.out.println(SubBucket);
                            Alldate.put("date", SubBucket);


                            ArrayBuckets.put(Alldate);
```

or something that fit your code.